# python move a shape in zigzag

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to write a code that moves a sphere in a zig-zag way across the screen from the upper left to the lower right. this is my attempt.

```
scene= canvas(width=500, height=500, autoscale=False)
xpos=-10
ypos=8
totaldistance=15
stepsize=0.1
nsteps=int(totaldistance/stepsize)
totaltime=20
timebetween=int(nsteps/totaltime)
s=sphere(pos=vector(-10,0,0), axis=vector(0,2,0))
for i in range(nsteps):
    rate(timebetween)
    xpos=xpos+stepsize
       xpos=xpos+stepsize
    if xpos==10:
        xpos=xpos-stepsize
    if xpos==1:
        xpos=xpos+stepsize 
    ypos=ypos-stepsize
    s.pos=vector(xpos,ypos,0)
```

I don't know how to tell the sphere to move in the other direction when it reaches certain position so that it forms a zig zag motion.

Comment: maybe you should use some variable `direction = "left"` and use it to run different code. OR you should use popular method - when it touchs border then change direction of speed `stepsize = -stepsize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popular method is to change direction

```
stepsize = -stepsize
```

And it needs to use separated `x_stepsize` and `y_stepsize`

like this

```
x_stepsize = stepsize
y_stepsize = -stepsize

for i in range(nsteps):
    xpos += x_stepsize
    ypos += y_stepsize

    if xpos >= 10:
        xpos = 10
        x_stepsize = -x_stepsize
    if xpos <= 1:
        xpos = 1
        x_stepsize = -x_stepsize

    s.pos = vector(xpos, ypos, 0)
```